# Identify this set with long black irregular shapes with light grey edges

Tags: set-identification

Please help me identify what this is please.

[image: long black irregular shapes with light grey edges]

Answer (score 3):

Based on part [18675pb13](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=18675pb13&in=S) it's 75179-1 [Kylo Ren's TIE Fighter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75179-1)

[image: 18675pb13]

[image: 75179-1]

Comment: That's the body on the left - but the wings on the right are from a different set entirely, right? This set doesn't have that much LtBley in it, and doesn't have **any** of the 10x10 wedge pieces.

Comment: the right wings look like they're from [75154 Tie Striker](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75154-1)